# Set env variable inside sudo statement - Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I need to modify an environment variable **inside a sudo statement**. The sudo statement includes some instructions.

In the example, I set the environment variable *VAR1* with the value "ABC".

Then, in the sudo statement (and only here), I need to change that value to "DEF". But the value did not change after I set the value to "DEF". Echo commands return "ABC" as the value of VAR1.

How can I change/set the value of the variable inside the sudo statement?

Here an example of the code I run:

```
#!/bin/bash
export VAR1="ABC"

sudo -u <user> -i sh -c "
         export VAR1="DEF";
         echo $VAR1;
"

echo $VAR1;
```

Extra info: I tryed the option -E of sudo, to preserve the environment variable at the moment of sudo invocation (source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337819/how-to-export-variable-for-use-with-sudo/337820), but the result did not change:

```
#env VAR1="DEF" sudo -u <user> -E -i sh -c " [...]"
```

Comment: `sudo env VAR1="DEF" sh -c '...'` may be less trouble -- you don't need to worry about making your definitions `eval`-safe, which is certainly a concern if you're trying to pass data from untrusted sources to a script running with escalated privileges. Though of course that doesn't solve the problem of double quotes causing early expansion -- you do indeed need to use single quotes for your script (same as without `sudo`; `sh -c "foo=bar; echo $foo"` is always broken, `sudo` or no).

Comment: @jww Huh? There's an MCVE right in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes to prevent the outer shell from interpolating `$VAR1`. You need `$VAR1` to be passed to the inner shell so it can expand it.

```
sudo -u <user> -i sh -c '
         export VAR1="DEF"
         echo "$VAR1"
'
```

It's also a good idea to quote variable expansions to [prevent globbing and splitting mishaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/expansion-of-a-shell-variable-and-effect-of-glob-and-split-on-it): write `"$VAR1"` instead of `$VAR1`.

(The semicolons aren't necessary since you have newlines.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export VAR1="ABC"

sudo -u <user> -i sh -c '
         export VAR1="DEF"
         echo "${VAR1}"
'

echo $VAR1;
```

as John Kugelman pointed out, you should use ' instead of " to wrap your command to avoid shell vars interpolation. Also, when referencing to `VAR` inside the command, use `"${}"` instead of `$`, this is what did the trick for me

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it should matter whether you write `$VAR1` or `${VAR1}`. Why do you think it makes a difference?

Comment: it did with me, using just `$` didn't work for me, I'm using bash so there shouldn't be any problem, and I honestly don't know why is not working

Comment: I just tried it. I didn't need the curly braces, but I did need to change `sh` to `bash` (combining `export` with the variable assignment is a `bash` extension) and add `;` at the end of the `export` line (it wasn't treating the newline as a statement terminator).

Comment: Mmmm, this is exactly what I run: `export V=1; sudo -i bash -c 'export V=2; echo "${V}"; echo "$V";'; echo $V;`, only the `${V}` and the last `$V` (outside sudo cmd) are being printed. Do you know why? I'm not an expert with bash and this is really interesting

Comment: It seems to be version-specific. I see what you see on OS X running bash 3.2.57, but not on Linux running 4.2.37.

Comment: Could also be related to the `sudo` version. If I don't use `sudo`, it works without braces on both systems. sudo 1.8.5p2 on Linux, 1.8.17p1 on OS X.

Comment: It makes sense, I'm using Linux with bash 4.3.48 and `sudo` 1.8.16. My `sudo` version is closer to your OS X's version, and also I can confirm too that it works as expected without using `sudo`, so we could be sure that is directly related to `sudo` in versions near of 1.8.16. I wonder if this could be considered as a bug

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454532/why-do-i-need-curly-braces-when-using-a-variable-in-sudo

Comment: Nice, thank you!, I will keep track of it. I hope someone could make it clear to us